# Looping through an object then through a nested array of objects--javascript react/redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to loop through an array to pull one piece of info from an object. Got it! However, I need to loop through an array within that same object after having gotten the first piece of data to pull more data from the nested array of objects. Any clue how I could make this work? I have tried multiple ways. I am now stuck at trying to run two if statements in this render function which react/redux is not "liking". I.e. it will not execute the 2nd if statement. Any help is appreciated. There is a sample of my data structure at the bottom Thanks!

```
    render(){
    let takePoll;
    let choices;
        if(this.props.polls.length > 0){
            takePoll =  this.props.polls.map( poll => {
                if (this.props.pollId === poll.id){ 
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <h2 className="take-poll">{poll.text}</h2>
                        </div>
                    )
                } 
            })
        }

        if(this.props.polls.length > 0){
            let choices = this.props.polls.map(poll => {
                if (this.props.pollId === poll.id){
                    return poll.choices.map(obj => {
                        return ( 
                            <div>
                                <h3>{obj.choice}</h3>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    return (
        <div>
            {takePoll}
            {choices}
        </div>
    )
}



//DATA STRUCTURE BELOW:

{
"id": "596dfbbc02c10a41e05a82d5",
"text": "which summer was hotter?",
"choices": [
    {
        "choice": "2017",
        "vote": "0"
    },
    {
        "choice": "2004",
        "vote": "0"
    }
],
"date": "2017-07-18T12:14:52.791Z" }
```

Comment: choice is already defined by let choices, you can't define it again. Remove the let tag again.

Answer (score 0):

Two if() statements that have the same exact variable/value check should not be your fix. Given what @Anamul suggested, you may want to try something like this:

```
render() {
  let takePoll;
  let choices;
  if (this.props.polls.length > 0) {
    takePoll = this.props.polls.map(poll => {
      if (this.props.pollId === poll.id) {
        return (
          <div>
            <h2 className="take-poll">{poll.text}</h2>
          </div>
        )
      } 
    })
    choices = this.props.polls.map(poll => {
      if (this.props.pollId === poll.id) {
        return poll.choices.map(obj => {
          return (
            <div>
              <h3>{obj.choice}</h3>
            </div>
          )
        })
      }
    })
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {takePoll}
      {choices}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well if I were you, I will do it in one loop

```
render(){
let takePoll = [];
let choices = [];

for(let i = 0; i < this.props.polls.length; i++) {
  let poll = this.props.polls[i]
    if (this.props.pollId === poll.id){
        takePool.push(
          <div>
              <h2 className="take-poll">{poll.text}</h2>
          </div>
        )
        choices.concat(poll.choices.map(obj => {
            return ( 
                <div>
                    <h3>{obj.choice}</h3>
                </div>
            )
        }))
    }
})

return (
    <div>
        {takePoll}
        {choices}
    </div>
)}
```

note that I have tested the code yet